# Stop Bullet from following player's position in javascript html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on a side project and I fell into a problem while trying to make the bullet.
Basically what my code does it that, when the player clicks the bullet shoots, but every time I move the mouse to rotate the player, The bullet follows. what I want it to do is after being fired should keep moving in the direction of the shot and not the player.

codepen link ---> https://codepen.io/robotosail/pen/abJLQKp

```
//the bullet code
let bullets = [];
function shootGun() {
  // increasing the bullets speed
  bullet.speedX = 3;
  bullets.push(bullet);
}
```

In the controls section

```
for (let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
  if (bullets[i] === undefined) continue;
  if (bullets[i].alive === false) {
    bullets.splice(i, 1);
    continue;
  }
}

if (punching) {
  arm1.position.x = 60;
  //the bullet
  //rotating the bullet
  shootGun();
  bullets.slice(bullet, 1);
}
```

in the init function

```
bullet = new Bullet({
  x: ammo.position.x,
  y: ammo.position.y,
  width: ammo.style.width,
  height: ammo.style.height,
  color: "black",
});

bullets.forEach((bullet) => {
  bullet.update();
  bullet.newPos();
  setTimeout(function () {
    bullet.alive = false;
  }, 1000);
});
```

I have approached this problem to the best of my knowledge.
please help!

Comment: I'd better create another canvas as a layer for the player. That's because you rotate whole scene for player, but needed to rotate the player only, then hold the angle and position of player and assign it to new bullet (with moving direction).

Comment: @Leonid Your comment is rather poor advice as using another canvas as a layer just for bullets is a massive unneeded composition  and rendering overhead (especially for lower end devices) when all that is needed is to use a separate transform for each bullet.

Comment: Your codepen is huge 600+ lines of code! can you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example it's very hard to debug code that large